# Elasticsearch Query time took increases.

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently I was trying to note down the average time taken by a query to execute. While continuously firing queries on elastic search, I noted that sometimes the took field in the response would suddenly spike. For example, if the query was returning 4-6 ms in took normally, it would return 30 ms unexpectedly in between.
This was the case with my other queries as well. So this anomaly does not seem query specific.

Can anyone explain the spikes that certainly happen in took field for this queries?

Answer (score 0):

While firing queries continuously, following things can lead to a spike in the time taken:

1. Garbage collection: Whenever there is large garbage collection process triggered internally, the time taken the Elasticsearch is expected to degrade. The variation depends on the time spent on process. To some extent this can be observed via Kibana's monitoring page. In such a scenario most likely the Aggregation queries which are memory intensive can get affected.
2. If the queries are being fired in parallel, there could be a congestion in the queued where Queries get stacked up. This could degrade the overall performance (increased memory consumption) for a short time due to the execution of multiple queries by multiple threads.
3. Tertiary activities: If the ES is busy with optimizing the segments which is an IO intensive operation, then search query could get impacted. If another operation like indexing is being done on the same index on which a query is being executed then this can influence as well.

Comment: Hi. I am quite sure that there are no queries running in parallel.

Comment: And There was no indexing between the consecutive queries as this was all running on my local machine.

Comment: Also the pattern was too frequent to be because of garbage collector. but I am using elasticsearch 2.1 with java 8 which has G1 garbage collector by default. Will this affect my querying time?

Comment: ES officially did not support G1 GC policy till v6.5 due to known bugs. I cannot exact;y say its impact on older version of ES.  Check out -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_g1gc_check.html